# Python socket сохранить socket юзера

Tags: python, сокет

Итак у меня есть вот такой простенький код, когда клиент отключается и подключается обратно на сервер уже не приходит никакой запрос как сделать чтобы после отключение юзер сохранялся что ли или что-то в этом роде.

```
def start_shell():
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 8888
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind((host, port))
    server.listen()
    while True:
        user, adress = server.accept()
        while True:
            data = user.recv(4096)
            if not data:
                continue
            print(data.decode('utf-8'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        import socket
    except:
        exit()

    start_shell()
```

И код клиента

```
import socket
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 8888

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((host, port))

while True:
    result = input('>>> ')
    if result == 'exit' or result == 'close':
        break
    client.send(result.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Это код сервера, а что у клиента? Клиент сам подключается к серверу, поэтому вопрос к реализации клиента

Comment: Да добавил его в пост посмотрите выше

Comment: А оберните код от `client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)` и ниже в еще один цикл `while True`

Comment: Но тогда он просто не запустится вовсе

Comment: Запустится и будет перезапускаться при каждом выходе из внутреннего `while` с `result = input('>>> ')`. Если добавите внутри первого `while` отлов ошибок через try/except, то еще можно будет обработать их и например повторить подключение к серверу или прервать работу скрипта

Comment: Возможно я неправильно описал проблему, при переподключения к серверу на сервер уже не поступает ничего я хочу чтобы после переключения я снова я отправлял что либо и север это принял если отключить сервер и снова подключится к нему все работает но вить сервер должен работать постоянно поэтому я хочу чтобы даже после переподключения к серверу я могу отправлять ему запрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отладил сервер. Причина в зацикливании, когда данных нет.

Вам нужно прерывать цикл через `break`:

```
...
    while True:
        user, adress = server.accept()
        while True:
            data = user.recv(4096)
            if not data:
                break
            print(data.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Вот спасибо да на этот раз получилось я примерно такое делал но не заканчивал цикл я забыл что первый цикл будет работать вы мне очень помогли!

Comment: @Dendi255, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)